# Use VBA to add a validation list to all blank cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a validation list to range of cells if they are blank. I start the process by looking up a value in column A and seeing if that value is on another list. If not then the cell should be left blank and a validation list should be added to that blank cell. I have tried it a number of ways but my For loop is clearly incorrect because after cycling through the blank cells are still blank. I have looked at a few solutions on SO and a few other sites but I have not found anything that resolves my issue.

```
 Sub FormulaTest()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim conv As Worksheet
Set conv = Sheets("Conversion")

lRow = conv.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

conv.Range("B2").Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Suggestions,4,FALSE),"""")"
conv.Range("B2").Copy
conv.Range("B3:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
conv.Range("B2:B" & lRow).Copy
conv.Range("B2:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & lRow).Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        With cell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=ValidList"
        End With
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your question and post some images of the data you’re working with.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an easier way to solve my issue. Since the user would be making selections from the same list I realized I could just add a validation list to their cell while keeping their answer.

```
Sub FormulaTest()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim conv As Worksheet
Set conv = Sheets("Conversion")

lRow = conv.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

conv.Range("B2").Formula = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Suggestions,4,FALSE),"""")"
conv.Range("B2").Copy
conv.Range("B3:B" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas

For i = 2 To lRow
    Cells(i, 2).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=ValidList"
Next i

End Sub
```